# Proving that a minimum is unique

Tags: derivatives

I want to prove that a function $f(x)$ has its unique minimum at $f(c)$. By that I mean, $f(c) < f(x)$ for all $x \neq c$. The strict inequality is obviously vital.

My question is, does this follow automatically if $f'(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = c$?

I've heard the words "sufficient, necessary" be thrown around when it comes to derivatives. What do they mean?

edit:

I forgot to mention: $f$ is bounded below by zero. It is quadratic in $\beta$.

Comment: No, it does not follow. Just consider the function $f(x)=x^3$. Then $f'(0)=0$, but 0 is not even a local minimum, let alone a global. --- Clearly, you will need stronger conditions on $f$ to make such a claim.

Comment: If in addition, you can show the function is bounded below, then I think the statement is correct.

Comment: Please see edit!

Comment: @user9527 Actually, strict inequality still will not be correct. Just consider $f(x)=(x-2)^2(x+2)^2$. Then if will have two minimums with the same value at different points.

Comment: @kholli But in that case, $f'(x) = 0$ does not have a unique solution, so it's fine right? I am asking that if $f'(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = c$, then $c$ is unique. In your case, that does not apply.

Comment: @kholli: In the question, it is assumed to have a unique stationary point, i.e., $f'(x)=0$ if and only if $x=c$.

Comment: @Masum: In response to edit: Yes, under those conditions it does hold. (Bounded below gives you the fact that it has a minimum, quadratic tells you that it is a global minimum).

Comment: @user9527 you still need stronger assumptions. $f(x)=|x|$ has a unique minimum, but the point is not even differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, I'm going to have to say no: being bounded and having a global local minima is not sufficient to show that the derivative will only be 0 when $x=c$.

For example take the dirty function that I just whipped up in Desmos to show a counterexample

$$
f(x) = \dfrac{x^5-x^4+x^3+x}{20e^{|x|}}+4
$$

[image]

This function is bounded both above and below and the local minima you find at $c=-4.756..$ is also equivilent to the global minima, which holds your condition that $f(x) > f(c) \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. However there is also a local maxima at $c'=5.134..$. By definition the derivative will be zero at both of these points, which runs counter to your original claim that $f'(x)=0$ only when $x=c$

Comment: I will remain neutral regarding your answer. The idea of him is totally right! I think he has only a strong intuition, but he does not have a formal education in such a topic. If the function actually achieves a minimum, it does follow automatically that a function has one global minimum if, $f'(x)=0$ if and only if $x=c$. It's a sufficient condition for having a unique global minimizer. The problem is that such a condition does not hold for all problems, as your example showed.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x)=x-x^3/3$  at $ [-1,1].$

for all $x\in ]-1, 1],$

$$f(-1)<f(x)$$

but
$$f'(1)=0$$